# Run SSH session and log to a file stdout from client adding timestamp

Tags: linux, logging, awk, ssh, timestamp

I need to collect debug traces from a SSH connection. I would like to run SSH client from a linux terminal, inside a screen session, being able to interact with the session to start traces and then have all the output logged to a file, but I also would like to add a timestamp in front of each line including the millisecond information.

I tried to use:

`ssh ... | awk '{ print strftime("%a\ %b\ %d\ %H:%M:%S.%N\ %Y"), $0; fflush(); }' | tee logfile`

it works but it has two problems: no milliseconds, because %N is not supported in strftime and the commands input from terminal are not visible until I send them.

Please consider that I probably cannot install linux packages (I am running this form a Qnap NAS) and I am not a master in linux environment

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `date` with `while` loop instead of `awk`

```
ssh ... | while read line; do echo "`date +'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%N %Y'` $line"; done | tee logfile
```

If you don't want to see timestamp on stdout and only log it and your shell is bash, then you can employ named pipes:

```
ssh ... | tee >(while read line; do echo "`date +'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%N %Y'` $line"; done >logfile)
```

Comment: First option works, but when I try to use the second one to exclude timestamp from terminal I receive a bash error (the system use sh, strangely bash is a symlink to sh and not the opposite). So I first entered in a bash shell via "bash" command and then from there no more errors but the logfile created is empty :(

Answer (score 0):

you can outsource date/time to shell where you can get milliseconds from system nanoseconds

```
   ... | awk 'BEGIN{cmd="date +%T.%3N"} { cmd | getline t; ...; close(cmd)}' |
```

you can extend it to add date fields as well. Not sure how well it will work for you...